# create dictionary in python using two sets

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I have to merge two sets:

```
colors={'GREEN','YELLOW','PURPLE','BLUE','RED'}
```

and

```
children={'uri','ron','sigalit','ruti','alon'}
```

into a single dictionary using children as keys.
i'm not allowed to use loops, and not allowed to use indexing.
any clues as to how to do this?

Comment: @Cyber Are you using Python 2.6 or earlier?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary 2.7. Did this change in 3.x?

Comment: @Cyber Yes, and it was back ported to Python 2.7 as well.

Comment: If you care which color gets mapped to which child, then you can't use sets: they have no defined ordering.

Comment: @Chen Davidov: perhaps you could explain why they must be sets, and why you cannot use loops or indexing?

Comment: Note that this operation makes absolutely no sense on sets as sets are unordered, and thus the resulting key:value pairs in the dictionary are going to be random. Well, not exactly random, but dependend on the used hash function and possible hash collisions in the set - but it's actually impossible to guarantee they are going to be in definition order.

Comment: i'm aware of that' but my teacher insists there is a way of doing it

Comment: what key is supposed to match to what value?

Comment: they're supposed to match in the order written

Comment: @ChenDavidov Then you're using a wrong data-structure, use list or tuple.

Comment: @ChenDavidov I'm sorry, but if your teacher says to use sets, and that they have to match in the order given, then your teacher doesn't know what they are talking about.  It won't work.

Comment: well' ill speak with him, thank you all very much anyways!

Comment: Your teacher does not seem to know how sets in python work. Sets are internally implemented as a hash table, each element is hashed and the only sense of "order" a Set has is the natural order of the hash values. E.g. you can build a set containing the values `[1,2,3]` in any permutation you like (1,2,3; 3,2,1; 2,1,3 etc), but when iterating over the resulting set you are always going to get 1 first, then 2, then 3. That's really simple to try out and demonstrate in the interactive interpreter, if you need to convince your teacher of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dict` comprehension.

```
children = {'uri','ron','sigalit','ruti','alon'}
colors = {'GREEN','YELLOW','PURPLE','BLUE','RED'}

>>> {x:y for x,y in zip(children,colors)}
{'uri': 'GREEN', 'ruti': 'BLUE', 'ron': 'YELLOW', 'alon': 'RED', 'sigalit': 'PURPLE'}
```

Comment: they have to remain as sets

Comment: @Chen Davidov `i'm not allowed to use loops`. Dict comprehension use a loop inside.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: colors={'GREEN','YELLOW','PURPLE','BLUE','RED'} 

In [2]: children={'uri','ron','sigalit','ruti','alon'}

In [3]: dict(zip(children, colors))
Out[3]: 
{'alon': 'GREEN',
 'ron': 'RED',
 'ruti': 'PURPLE',
 'sigalit': 'BLUE',
 'uri': 'YELLOW'}
```

Comment: the order of the sets doesn't remain

Comment: @ChenDavidov sets don't have order, so I don't think that'd be possible

Comment: Why can't you use `list(colors)` and `list(children)` ? Set is unordered collection

Comment: @ChenDavidov: since sets are unordered there is nothing that can be done about *that*.

Comment: my teacher insists i have to do it without conversion to other data types

Comment: @ChenDavidov Either your teacher is confused, or you are confused. It isn't possible.

Comment: @ChenDavidov Unless you look into how the unordered 'order' of sets is determined based on the CPython implementation. Then prefix and strip the strings after looping so they stay in the desired order. But I highly doubt that's the task your teacher is trying to get you to do- it seems crazy